# Castle Windsor enable or disable interceptors during run time

Tags: logging, castle-windsor, aop, interceptor, application-restart

Is it possible whilst an application (of any type e.g. console, web, web role in azure etc.) to switch castle windsor interceptors on or off to avoid an application restart?

My scenario is to use an Interceptor like that below, to log method entry and exit with arguments.

```
public class ExampleInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Before method: {0}", invocation.Method.Name));
        invocation.Proceed();
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("After method: {0}", invocation.Method.Name));
    }
}
```

My initial approach was to do something like this:

```
public class InterceptorSelector : IModelInterceptorsSelector
{
    public static bool InterceptorOn = false;

    public bool HasInterceptors(ComponentModel model)
    {
        return
            typeof(ExampleInterceptor) != model.Implementation
            && InterceptorOn
            && model.Implementation.Namespace.StartsWith("MvcApplication1");
    }

    public InterceptorReference[] SelectInterceptors(ComponentModel model, InterceptorReference[] interceptors)
    {
        return new[]
        {
            InterceptorReference.ForType<ExampleInterceptor>()
        };
    }
}
```

However I found that once the interceptor has handled a method once, there must be some internal caching (for performance benefit no doubt) as the method does not get hit again in the InterceptorSelector.

The primary use case I have for this is a WebApi hosted in azure serving hundreds (if not 1000s) of requests per second over multiple VM instances. In the event of needing to debug the live environment I want to enable verbose logging on one of these instances but at the same time not want to take the VM instance out of action when enabling this logging.

Comment: Did you check that both methods HasInerceptors, but also SelectInterceptors are not called ? I would expect that the latter is called on every creation of a component. I thought that the first method is mererly called once, so that windsor will not call the second for components that never need interceptors selected.

Answer (score 1):

Switching logic in runtime can be easily implemented with configuration switch or you can do it like K.Kozmic as shown in his tutorial on dynamic proxy [here](http://kozmic.net/2008/12/16/castle-dynamicproxy-tutorial-part-i-introduction/).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static event which you'll suscribe the interceptors to, then disabling the interceptors would be done by manipulating the controller class

```
public class ChangeInterceptorSettingsEventArgs : EventArgs {}

public class MyInterceptorsController
{
    public delegate void ChangeInterceptorSettingsEvent(ChangeInterceptorSettingsEventArgs args);
    public static event ChangeInterceptorSettingsEvent ChangeInterceptorSettings;

    public void ChangeInterceptorsSettings(ChangeInterceptorSettingsEventArgs args)
    {
        if (ChangeInterceptorSettings != null)
        {
            ChangeInterceptorSettings(args);
        }
    }
}
```

Then create the interceptor and register an event handler

```
public class ExampleInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public bool WriteThings { get; set; }
    public ExampleInterceptor()
    {
        MyInterceptorsController.ChangeInterceptorSettings += MyInterceptorsController_ChangeInterceptorSettings;
    }

    void MyInterceptorsController_ChangeInterceptorSettings(ChangeInterceptorSettingsEventArgs args)
    {
        WriteThings = !WriteThings; // this is not very smart, 
        // but I don't want to populate the args in this example
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        if (WriteThings) {Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Before method: {0}", invocation.Method.Name));}
        invocation.Proceed();
        if (WriteThings) {Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("After method: {0}", invocation.Method.Name));}
    }
}
```

Finally to use it, just call the event from the controller

```
MyInterceptorsController.ChangeInterceptorsSettings(new ChangeInterceptorSetingsEventArgs())
// populate the args parameters with what you need
```

---

So, if you want to go and rip some interceptors out of the object you have resolved, you could always get the private field that contains the interceptors and change it at runtime. I don't really recommend that *before* making sure that the existence of an interceptor has such a performance hit:

```
resolvedObject
    .GetType()
    .GetField("__interceptors")
    .SetValue(resolvedObject, new IInterceptor[0]);
// or whatever interceptor array you want to set
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @samy. I quite like the idea, however from this approach I believe the interceptor would need to be switched on permanently and therefore I am unsure on what the performance would be like. I have read another post seeing a performance degradation of 30% (older version of castle), which is why I am/was hoping there was a way of removing an interceptor from castle just like the adding -Container.Kernel.ProxyFactory.AddInterceptorSelector(new InterceptorSelector()). I am assuming castle likes to have everything registered upfront and what I am after is not possible

Comment: ps @samy, I will leave it a couple of days to see if there are any other suggestions and if not will mark your reply as the answer.

Comment: Once you have created a component with an interceptor, other parts of your code will have a reference to your interceptor, not the instance of you component. So removing an interceptor from a running component is impossible. If you are worried about performance, could tyr using a class proxy (this is in essence a dervided class). You can force this by registering the component itself as its interface as well.

Comment: Thanks @Marwijn, so ultimately what we are saying here is if an interceptor is registered, it cannot be de-registered and there will always be a check for a component registered with windsor to see whether or not to use an interceptor

Comment: @Danjuro, I'm going to look into it a bit more, but initially I was trying to answer how to switch interceptors on and off, not how to manage the interception pipeline. Regarding the performance, did you time it? It looks like quite a performance hit, and since it is not trivial to measure I wonder how it was done.

Comment: @samy I believe once a component is instantiated  (ie resolved from the container) it is not possible anymore to remove the interceptor. I do not believe it impossible to avoid creating an interceptor for a newly resolved component. To improve your performance you might want to try creating a class proxy, which is in essence a derived class. You can do this by registering the component as an additional service.

Comment: @Marwijn Well you can always go ahead and drill down in your resolved proxied object: `resolvedObject.GetType().GetField("__interceptors").SetValue(resolvedObject, new IInterceptor[0])` but this doesn't look very safe

Comment: Adding the reflection to override interceptors to my answer. Would really love to hear about performance though

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude/add interceptors at runtime this way:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IResolver iResolver {get;set;}
    public IService someService {get;set;}  

    private UsageMethod()
    {
        ExcludeInterceptors(someService, new [] {typeof(Interceptor1),typeof(Interceptor2)};
        AddInterceptor(someService, typeof(Interceptor1), 0};
    }

    private Castle.DynamicProxy.IInterceptor[] getInterceptorsField(object service)
    {
        var field = service.GetType().GetField("__interceptors");
        return field.GetValue(service) as Castle.DynamicProxy.IInterceptor[];
    }

    private void ExcudeInterceptors(object service, params Type[] interceptorTypes2exclude)
    {           
        var newInterceptors = getInterceptorsField(service).Where(x => !interceptorTypes2exclude.Contains(x.GetType())).ToArray();
        field.SetValue(service, newInterceptors);
    }

    private void AddInterceptor(object service, Castle.DynamicProxy.IInterceptor interceptorType2add, int position)
    {           
        var newInterceptors = getInterceptorsField(service).ToList();
        newInterceptors.Insert(position, iResolver.Resolve(interceptorType2add));
        field.SetValue(service, newInterceptors.ToArray());
    }
}
```

> P.S. Was tested with Castle.Windsor 3.3.0